# Planning Kubernetes-Cluster on Azure

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I´m planning a new web-project and want to implement node.js microservices. Now I´ve read a lot and found out that it will be a recommended way to do that with docker/kubernetes for availability and scaling.

It will be my first project and a have a lot of question now. Hopefully the community helps me out a bit with it:

Kubernetes-Cluster:
One of my first questions is the cluster. What is the best way to start with the cluster? Azure AKS is mostly used in web-tutorials, but isn´t it possible to start with an own server installing Docker and Kubernetes via a webhosting?

My biggest problem is that I don´t know to to calculate prices on Azure. For me it is clear that the cluster hasn´t any costs, but how do I calculate VM and Traffic.

And what about having a lot of API´s, should be each API an own AKS-Service on Azure = 1 VM which is 24 hours up and running?

It should be a webproject, all API´s must be available 24 hours.
Has anyone experiences with using Azure AKS with an similar project and has some explanations for me.

If it is possible with an webhosting package, has someone a tutorial how to start with it?

Thanks to all for help, hopefully there is someone to clarify some points for me.

Comment: This question seems way too broad to answer in a stackoverflow answer. Many of the questions you have are very opinionated and you will get a different response from almost everyone. I would personally recommend that you work out the size of your cluster and what you need first. You can use something like minikube or better kind (https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/) to start testing your microservice / API architecture locally. Focussing on one provider for your production cluster this early on is not beneficial IMO.

Comment: thanks for your answer... I will give this a try.

Answer (score 0):

According to [@Bricktop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4360457/bricktop) -Please start using [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/) to get practice:
Locally:

- [Minikube](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/minikube/)
- [Kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/)

In cloud (please create free account) you can find more details below:

- [Gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/free/)
- [Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/)
- [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/free/?all-free-tier.sort-by=item.additionalFields.SortRank&all-free-tier.sort-order=asc&awsf.Free%20Tier%20Types=categories%23featured)

After getting some knowledge about your solution, how it works what resources are necessary (related to this project - please use monthly billings provided by the Cloud-provider of your choice. You can use also "Pricing Calculator" from the official websites. 
Hope this help